# Cake Php Find something in another controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I tried to previously to simplify the question. This is the real code

I don't have a problem with'find'. i have a problem with grabbing the data after I find. I'm using this to validate. If i wasn't using this to validate i can show print_r onto the page and get my vars. But i'm working in this middle ground, I don't know how to find my vars. I installted the debugger.

I didn't use the user auth cause this is a quick project and i'm not a master at it yet and security is not a big deal for this project.

my table

user
[id][name][attending][limit]

guest
[id][user_id][name]

```
public function add($id = null) {



    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Guest->create();

        $user_id = $this->request->data['Guest']['user_id'];
        //i have a hidden input in the from that is why this works, i know this isn't the right way tto do this.

        $guest_count = $this->Guest->find('count', array(
                                                        'conditions' => 
                                                            array('user_id' => $user_id )
                                                        )
                                                    );

        $userData = $this->Guest->User->find('all', array('id' => $user_id ));
        //i got this this works


        $guest_limit = $userData['limit'];//this doesn't work


        if($guest_count >= $guest_limit)
        {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You can\'t add any more guest '));
            $this->set('dataView', $this->request->data );
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view' , $id));

        } else {

            if ($this->Guest->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Guest added'));
                $this->set('dataView', $this->request->data );
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view' , $id));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid name entered'));
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view' , $id));

            }
        }
    }
    /**/
```

Comment: Show me your Guest and Item table schema.... And also Guest model...

Comment: And I have to tell you one thing bro... Read Cakephp documentation from up to bottom... I bet, you will never ask that kinds of silly question..

Comment: i couldn't find in the documentation where they speak about getting a table when your in another controller. Thank you for your help. I edited with the table.

Comment: I guess you didn't read well....

Comment: i'm not here to fight, if you dont want to help thats fine
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: I don't mean to hard you bro... Seriously, read the documentation up to bottom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this-- here is a simple one--

## Guest.php

```
class Guest extends AppModel{
   public $hasMany = array('Item');

}
```

## On GuestsController.php

```
public function view($id = null) {
$user_id = $id;
$guest_with_item = $this->Guest->Item->find('all', array(
                                                'conditions' => array(
                                                    'user_id' => $user_id )
                                                ),
                                               'recursive' => 1
                                            ); 
}
```

## After updating question

```
$userData = $this->Guest->User->find('first', array(
                                                'conditions' => array(
                                                    'User.id' => $user_id
                                                )
                                            )
                                        );
 $guest_limit = $userData['User']['limit'];
```

Comment: this will retrieve Item along with Guest... And, You forget to add `id` field on Item table... This will cause problem for sure...

Comment: i got that part but how do i get the data for example $guest_with_item['description'] is that how i get it? I install the debugger, i'm getting errors on that part

Comment: I really don't get you question... If you go with `$guests = $this->Guest->find('all');` this will also fetch item with this. Now, so see the result write `debug($guests)`....And if you just wants to get Item, the go with Item.

Comment: I updated the question to provide the real problem. I should of do it from the beginning. i was trying to simply the question. It is a continuation of the problem you solved for me previously

Answer (score 0):

**AppModel.php**

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $recursive = -1;
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Containable'
    );
}
```

**Item.php**

```
class Item extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Guest');
}
```

**Guest.php**

```
class Guest extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Item');
}
```

**Guest Controller**

```
//or find first. it depends on how many rows with the same user_id You can have.
$this->Guest->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Guest.user_id' => $user_id
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Item'
    )
));
```

And yes, You should read [Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) few times more